# Does logback.xml <springProfile> tag not work for a Spring MVC project?

Tags: spring-mvc, logback, spring-profiles

My logback.xml file for a Spring MVC project looks something like this:

```
<springProfile name="local">
    <appender name="local">  . . .
    </appender>

    <logger name="xxxx.xxxx" level="DEBUG" additivity="false">
        <appender-ref ref="local" />
    </logger>

    <root level="info">
        <appender-ref ref="local" />
    </root>
</springProfile>

<springProfile name="stage">
    <appender name="stage">  . . .
    </appender>

    <logger name="xxxx.xxxx" level="DEBUG" additivity="false">
        <appender-ref ref="stage" />
    </logger>

    <root level="info">
        <appender-ref ref="stage" />
    </root>
</springProfile>
```

On running I get errors like :
h.qos.logback.core.joran.spi.Interpreter@4:31 - no applicable action for [springProfile], current ElementPath  is [[configuration][springProfile]]

Are Spring Profiles not supported for logback in a Spring MVC project? I could see similar code work in a Spring Boot project just fine.

Answer (score 2):

In order to use springProfile tag, you need to change the name of your logback file from logback.xml to logback-spring.xml.